# Linq to NHibernate: how to get a list of child objects without having the lists nested

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I have a Linq to NHibernate query as follows:

```
var profile = 
    from UserProfile up in _Session.Query<UserProfile>()
        .Fetch(x=>x.Messages)
    where up.UserName == userName
    select up.Messages;
```

this returns an `IQueryable<IList<UserMessage>>` which I then have to run a `SelectMany()` on.  I'd prefer if I could just return an `IQueryable<UserMessage>` object instead, especially as the query will never return more than one user profile.  Can this be done, or am I stuck with the extra step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you map the other side of the navigation e.g have a `UserProfile` property on the `UserMessage` class, your can start from `UserMessage`:

```
var messages = 
    from UserMessage um in _Session.Query<UserMessage>()
    where um.UserProfile.UserName == userName
    select um;
```

Otherwise you need to use `SelectMany()` to get a flattened out list.

Answer (score 1):

Could you query the messages table directly and use the reverse association?

```
IQueryable<Message> messages = ...;
var filtered = from m in messages
    where m.UserProfile.UserName == userName
    select m;
```

Also, if you're willing to forgo query syntax you could make this shorter with:

```
var profile = _Session.Query<UserProfile>()
    .Where(up => up.UserName == userName)
    .SelectMany(up => up.Messages);
```